# How to factor sub group by category?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I  have some code that displays the abundance of phyla, and genus within that phyla, as a stacked bar graph. I edited the code such that all the NA elements appear at the top of each bar and the more abundant elements appear at the bottom, however, this threw off my color palette which assigned the colors based on phyla group, and within that group by alphabet. For example, the Bacteriodetes phyla were assigned the color blue with each genus within the phyla being assigned a shade of blue in alphabetical order.

I believe I can change the levs variable to sort the elements alphabetically and grouped by phyla, but I haven't figured out a way to do that. Currently, however, the levs variable sorts the elements by abundance which is something I want to keep.

```
#makes color pallete
ColourPalleteMulti <- function(df, group, subgroup){

  # Find how many colour categories to create and the number of colours in each
  categories <- aggregate(as.formula(paste(subgroup, group, sep="~" )), df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
  category.start <- (scales::hue_pal(l = 100)(nrow(categories))) # Set the top of the colour pallete
  category.end  <- (scales::hue_pal(l = 40)(nrow(categories))) # set the bottom

  # Build Colour pallette
  colours <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(categories),
                           function(i){
                             colorRampPalette(colors = c(category.start[i], category.end[i]))(categories[i,2])}))
  return(colours)
}

library(tidyverse)
library("phyloseq"); packageVersion("phyloseq")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
data("GlobalPatterns")

#filter phyloseq data
TopNOTUs <- names(sort(taxa_sums(GlobalPatterns), TRUE)[1:100])
gp.ch   <- prune_species(TopNOTUs, GlobalPatterns)

#create dataframe
mdf = psmelt(gp.ch)
mdf$group <- paste0(mdf$Phylum, "-", mdf$Genus, sep = "")

#factor by abundance
levs <- names(sort(tapply(mdf$Abundance, mdf$Genus, sum)))
#load colors
colours <-  ColourPalleteMulti(mdf, "Phylum", "Genus")

#put NA at the top
mdf %>%
  mutate(Genus = fct_explicit_na(Genus, "NA"),
         Genus = factor(Genus, levels = c("NA", levs))) %>%
  #graph
  ggplot(aes(Phylum)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Genus), colour = "grey", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual("Genus", values=c("#FFFFFF",colours)) +
  ggtitle("Phylum and Genus Frequency") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Running this code reveals a bar graph with colors in odd places. Ideally, each bar in the graph will be a primary color with each stack being a different shade of the color. The color palette is being created correctly, but the colors are assigned incorrectly because of the aforementioned issues. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You're doing some tricky stuff here! I think it's hard to do this in a function and the biggest snag is putting the NAs at the top. Using just `tidyverse` piping, I was able to put this together.

This is your base set up + a little prep for folks without `phyloseq`

```r
# how to install if needed
#source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
#biocLite('phyloseq')
library(tidyverse)
library(phyloseq)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
data("GlobalPatterns")

# filter phyloseq data
TopNOTUs <- names(sort(taxa_sums(GlobalPatterns), TRUE)[1:100])
gp.ch <- prune_species(TopNOTUs, GlobalPatterns)

# create dataframe
mdf <- psmelt(gp.ch)
```

First I collapse the records into counts `n`

```r
prep <-
  mdf %>%
  mutate(Genus = fct_explicit_na(Genus, "NA")) %>% 
  # summarizes data
  count(Phylum, Genus) %>% # returns n as a count
  mutate(
    group = paste(Phylum, Genus, sep = "-"),
    Phylum = fct_reorder(Phylum, n, sum),
    has_genus = Genus != "NA"
  ) %>% 
  # this step helps with the factor ordering
  arrange(Phylum, has_genus, n) %>% 
  mutate(group = fct_inorder(group)) %>% 
  # I then find some totals & an rank based on the value of n
  group_by(Phylum) %>% 
  mutate(
    ord = row_number(),
    total = n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

#  Phylum         Genus             n group                      has_genus   ord total
#  <fct>          <fct>         <int> <chr>                      <lgl>     <int> <int>
#  Tenericutes    NA               52 Tenericutes-NA             FALSE         1     2
#  Tenericutes    Clostridium      26 Tenericutes-Clostridium    TRUE          2     2
#  Actinobacteria NA              130 Actinobacteria-NA          FALSE         1     3
#  Actinobacteria Rothia           26 Actinobacteria-Rothia      TRUE          2     3
#  Actinobacteria Bifidobacter~    78 Actinobacteria-Bifidobact~ TRUE          3     3
```

Then I use the factor values to populate the `hcl()` function (similar to your `hue_pal()`

```r
df <-
  prep %>% 
  mutate(
    group = fct_inorder(group), # ordering in the stack
    hue = as.integer(Phylum)*25,
    light_base = 1-(ord)/(total+2),
    light = floor(light_base * 100)
  ) %>% 
  # if the genus is missing, use white, otherwise create a hexcode
  mutate(hex = ifelse(!has_genus, "#ffffff", hcl(h = hue, l = light)))
```

Then the plot

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Phylum, n)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = group), colour = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = df$hex, breaks = (df$group)) +
  ggtitle("Phylum and Genus Frequency") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

For your second question, keep all of the above code for `prep` and `df` and then join these to your original `mdf` table. The purpose of the `df` table is only to generate the colors and `prep` is a helper table. There should be a 1:1 between `genus` and `hex`. Including the `sample` column in `prep` returns 780 rows instead of 30 and there is no longer a 1:1. This is why you are not getting the results you would like. (I think it is the `ord` column that gets thrown off). So use the above and then add this. I included a `set.seed()` and `sample_frac()` to make the changes more obvious. I also rotated it for readability.

```r
set.seed(1234)
final_df <- 
  mdf %>% 
  sample_frac(0.9) %>% 
  mutate(
    Genus = fct_explicit_na(Genus, "NA"),
    # these 2 lines will sort in descending order by Proteobacteria
    rank = as.integer(Phylum == "Proteobacteria" & Genus != "NA"), # T/F == 1/0
    Sample = fct_reorder(Sample, rank, mean)
  ) %>% 
  count(Phylum, Genus, Sample, rank) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% select(-n))


ggplot(final_df, aes(Sample, n)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = group), position="fill") +#
  scale_fill_manual("Genus", values = df$hex, breaks = (df$group)) +
  ggtitle("Phylum and Genus Frequency") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, expand = expand_scale(0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. I definitely have a lot to learn.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question below. Could you explain what is causing this problem and suggest a solution?

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate your thorough responses.